# Facebook Post as a image

Tags: facebook, oauth, facebooker2

I wants to post a post on Facebook as a Image not a text (and not as album too) , And I'm using below code :

```
def facebook_page
@page ||= Mogli::Page.new(:id => facebook_page_id, :client => Mogli::Client.new(facebook_page_token))
end

def post_to_facebook_page()
    post_params = {
    :message     => "message,"
    :link        => "url.jpeg"
    :name        => "name",
    :description => "description",
    :picture     => "picture_url"
   } 
    facebook_page.feed_create(Mogli::Post.new(post_params))
    rescue Mogli::Client::OAuthException, Mogli::Client::HTTPException => e
   Rails.logger.error("Unable to post to Facebook page #{facebook_page_id} due to #{e.message} on #{Time.now}")
end
```

But it is not posting as I expected :
Here is the output:
http://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100004124073785 all posts are as a text and

I expected :

http://www.facebook.com/bigjoneschicago?fref=ts find first post "Handmade pasta new on the menu tonight" , Could any one help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

You don’t want to post a link, but a photo instead: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#photos

*Edit in response to comment:*

Using `source` parameter requires data formated like an actual HTTP file upload. If you want to upload a picture using it’s publicly reachable URL, use parameter `url` instead.

And yes, if you don’t specify an album to upload to explicitly, the photo will go to an album named after your app. You can upload to a specific album instead, but that requires permission `user_photos`.

Comment: I'm using this {:source=>"https://fbcdn-sphotos-d-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-ash3/c67.0.403.403/p403x403/12172_10151311056527497_1467682994_n.jpg", :message=>"111message"}
@page.photos_create(Mogli::Post.new(post_params))
and giving me error Mogli::Client::OAuthException: (#324) Requires upload file
also I think It will create a untitled albums. :( By the way thank you so much...

Comment: Warning: property url doesn't exist for class Mogli::Post..
Also I don't want to create an album, simply like when you create a post you have an options in facebook "status","photo" ,"Place" so I just wanted to use Photo action. when you use this it will not collapse all post in once. But If I'm creating a photos as text , they getting shrink in one post as happens normally when you uplaod photos... :(

Comment: I have done by this :
page = Mogli::Page.new(:id => facebook_page_id, :client => Mogli::Client.new(facebook_page_token))
albums = page.albums
album = albums.map{|album| album if album.name == "Timeline Photos"}.compact.first
facebook_page.client.post("#{album.id}/photos", nil, {:url =>post_params[:picture] ,:name =>"#{post_params[:message]} : #{post_params[:description]}"}) By the way thank you so much @CBroe